# Разборка одного момента в хеш-таблице

Tags: c++, хеширование

Есть код, не могу разобраться как работает `put` в классе `HashMap()`
   Разъясните мне пожалуйста...
На сколько я понял мы обращаемся к `put` и передаем ключ елемента и само число. Потом ищем остаток ключ+сам объем списка. Зачем он нужен этот остаток ?. С `while` первое условие понятное, вроде как, а вот со вторым не пойму, зачем нужен указатель ключа??.. `hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;` и что мы получаем(какую пользу от элемента выше)?

```
class HashEntry {
    private:
          int key;
          int value;
    public:
          HashEntry(int key, int value) {
                this->key = key;
                this->value = value;
          }

          int getKey() {
                return key;
          }

          int getValue() {
                return value;
          }
    };
    const int TABLE_SIZE = 129;

    class HashMap {
    private:
          HashEntry **table;
    public:
          HashMap() {
                table = new HashEntry*[TABLE_SIZE];
                for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                      table[i] = NULL;
          }

          int get(int key) {
                int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
                while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->getKey() != key)
                      hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;
                if (table[hash] == NULL)
                      return -1;
                else
                      return table[hash]->getValue();
          }

          void put(int key, int value) {
                int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
                while (table[hash] != NULL && table[hash]->getKey() != key)
                      hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;
                if (table[hash] != NULL)
                      delete table[hash];
                table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);
          }

          ~HashMap() {
                for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
                      if (table[i] != NULL)
                            delete table[i];
                delete[] table;
          }
    };
```

Comment: Это нужно для разрешения коллизий. Предположим, что два элемента имеют равный хеш, тогда их надо было бы поместить в одну ячейку. Можно вместо этого помещать элемент в следующую свободную ячейку, что в коде и происходит. Это метод разрешения коллизий называется `метод цепочек`, существуют и другие. Статьи по теме: [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Хеш-таблица#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D0.B7.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.88.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B8.D0.B9), [итмоконспекты](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=Разрешение_коллизий)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HashMap реализует простейшее отображение `ключ->значение` используя хэш таблицу. Метод `put` предназначен для добавление `int` значения по `int` ключу. Вначале с помощью `int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);` мы получаем индекс возможного места в таблице, куда нужно разместить ключ и значение, берётся остаток от деления чтобы во-первых индекс вмещался в размер таблицы, во-вторых чтобы при равновероятном распределении ключей они попадали равномерно на всю таблицу. В настоящих реализациях хеш таблиц на самом деле ключ нужно хешировать через какой-то быстрый алгоритм аналогичный например CRC32, т.е. `index = CRC32(key) % TABLE_SIZE`, в нашем примере как понимаю простейшая демо реализация хеш таблиц. Далее от найденного индекса мы двигаемся вперёд пока либо место занято либо ключ отличается у хранимого элемента, движение вперёд идёт за счёт `hash = (hash + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;`, остаток от деления нужен чтобы начать с начала если мы дошли до конца таблицы. Т.е. получается в хеш таблице вначале примерно попадаем на случайное место а потом ищем себе место подходящее вблизи стартового индекса, место которое ещё не занято. Т.к. разные ключи могут иметь одинаковый хеш и значит одинаковый стартовый индекс, поэтому нужно продвинуться на соседние пустые места, это называется разрешением коллизий, т.е. когда два ключа попали в одну ячейку нужно как-то решить эту проблему (в нашем случаее это продвижение на ближайшее свободное место). Далее если `table[hash] != NULL` это означает что мы нашли элемент с тем же ключом, тогда его удаляем (`delete table[hash];`) чтобы разместить поверх новый. На найденное свободное место теперь размещаем новую пару ключ/значение `table[hash] = new HashEntry(key, value);`.